# How do you find the radius?

Tags: geometry

Can someone tell me how you can find the radius of the circle in the figure given below:

[image]

Given:
$$RS = WS$$

I have tried all I know but I just dont understand how can you use only information related to angles to find the length of the radius.

Comment: Could you solve the problem if the angle were 90 degrees instead?  (This is meant to be a hint.)

Comment: You can not. You need the length of $RS$ for example.

Comment: I guess you're expected to find it in terms of the lengths of those chords. Like the radius is $c \cdot |RS|$ for whatever the length of $RS$ is. @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: If so it's just $RS$.

Comment: So there is no way - no fricking way- that I can find the length of the radius without the length of the chords. RIGHT????

Comment: No. You can scale the figure by any factor (say 2), and the angle will be the same. The only thing you can say is the radius in terms of $|RS|$

Comment: Clearly the picture is scale invariant...you can get any length you want for the radius.  It seems clear that you are meant to show that the radius equals the length $RS$.

Comment: But, you can use the [Inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) to find the radius in terms of $\overline{RS}$.

Comment: Maybe you could apply the radius-of-a-sector if you shift the angle to be on the center as in:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274036/how-to-the-find-the-radius-of-a-sector

Answer (score 0):

Set $S = (0,0)$, and  W.L.O.G. assume that the vertical coordinate of W and R is the same. Thus $W = (\sqrt{3}L/2,L/2)$ and $R = (-\sqrt{3}L/2,L/2)$, with $L = RS=SW$.

Because $R,S$ and $W$ are points on a circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$, the following equations should be satisfied

$$ (0-a)^2+(0-b)^2 = r^2$$
$$ (\sqrt{3}L/2-a)^2+(L/2-b)^2 = r^2$$
$$ (-\sqrt{3}L/2-a)^2+(L/2-b)^2 = r^2$$

From the two last equations, we have $a=0.$ Thus, we will have the system

$$ b^2 = r^2 $$

$$ 3L^2/4 +(L/2-b)^2 = r^2,$$

which gives $r = L.$

Answer (score 0):

Connect points $R,S,W$ to the center of the circle $C$. Note that the triangles $RCS$ and $SCW$ are congruent and isosceles (as two out of three sides are equal to the radius). Thus, angles $RSC$ and $WSC$ are equal and must be of $60^0$. Hence, all angles in both triangles are the same $(60^0)$, and the radius = $RS = WS$.

Comment: Yes I already know that but if RS and WS are not given can you find the radius?

Comment: No, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out loud:
Using the information from [Find the radius from a sector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274036/how-to-the-find-the-radius-of-a-sector), and knowing that a central angel is 2 times the angle given, I reached this solution.

*I am not sure it is correct though, but I don't know what is wrong with it if it is incorrect.*

[image]

Comment: How did you find the arc length? How did you find $L$?

Comment: Arc length AC is the value of the central angle = L = 240.

Comment: I suggest you verify this by actually drawing it. Unfort. I don't have the tools!